# Swap controls in TableLayoutPanel Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a need to swap controls in a TableLayoutPanel. They are in separate rows. I've tried the suggested code but to no avail. Is there a solution this other than removing all the controls and re adding? The answer can be in C# or VB.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim c1 As Control = Me.tlp.GetControlFromPosition(0, 0)
    Dim c2 As Control = Me.tlp.GetControlFromPosition(0, 1)

    If c1 IsNot Nothing And c2 IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.tlp.SetRow(c2, 0)
        Me.tlp.SetRow(c1, 1)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the code to swap controls in a `TableLayoutPanel` - you have two options.

1) **Swap by reference to controls**:

```
Private Sub SwapControls(tlp As TableLayoutPanel, ctl1 As Control, ctl2 As Control)
  Dim ctl1pos As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = tlp.GetPositionFromControl(ctl1)
  tlp.SetCellPosition(ctl1, tlp.GetPositionFromControl(ctl2))
  tlp.SetCellPosition(ctl2, ctl1pos)
End Sub
```

It does not depend on where controls are located in `TableLayoutPanel` - could be different rows, columns or both.

Sample usage:

```
SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, Button1, Button2)
```

2) **Swap by column/row index**:

```
Private Sub SwapControls(tlp As TableLayoutPanel, pos1 As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition, pos2 As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition)
  Dim ctl1 As Control = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(pos1.Column, pos1.Row)
  Dim ctl2 As Control = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(pos2.Column, pos2.Row)
  SwapControls(tlp, ctl1, ctl2)
End Sub
```

Sample usage:

```
SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 0), New TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 0))
```

Solutions are based around [TableLayoutPanel.SetRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setrow.aspx) help article on MSDN and some research on its decompiled representation. Both were tested and deemed working.

Comment: today I needed exactly this :) Thanks God I found. I also had to translate in c#, but was simple. Many thanks.

Comment: Remember to swap the TabIndexes too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed length `TableLayoutPanel`, you may use `FlowLayoutPanel` (then length of it controls must have equal `FlowLayoutPanel` length):

```
Dim c1 As Control = Button1
Dim c2 As Control = CheckBox1

Dim i1 = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.IndexOf(c1)
Dim i2 = FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.IndexOf(c2)

FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(c1, i2)
FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(c2, i1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Same in C# code:
swapping / exchanging controls at any positions 1 and 2:

```
private void SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel tlp, TableLayoutPanelCellPosition cpos1, TableLayoutPanelCellPosition cpos2)
{
    var ctl1 = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(cpos1.Column, cpos1.Row);
    var ctl2 = tlp.GetControlFromPosition(cpos2.Column, cpos2.Row);
    if (ctl1 != null) // position1 can be empty
        tlp.SetCellPosition(ctl1, cpos2);
    if (ctl2 != null) // position2 can be empty
        tlp.SetCellPosition(ctl2, cpos1);
}
```

Sample of usage:

```
SwapControls(TableLayoutPanel1, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(0, 0), new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(1, 0))
```

Answer (score -1):

After searching around for a day and not coming up with nothing I finally took a shot in the dark and found the answer. You need to use the SetChildIndex of the control in the table. See Below...

Note: this only works if you add controls to TableLayoutPanel without row or column index.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tlp.RowStyles.Clear()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        Dim txt As New TextBox
        txt.Text = i
        txt.Name = "txt" & i
        tlp.Controls.Add(txt) 'this works
        'tlp.Controls.Add(txt, 0, i) 'this will not work when button is clicked
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim c1 As Control = Me.tlp.GetControlFromPosition(0, 0)
    Dim c2 As Control = Me.tlp.GetControlFromPosition(0, 1)

    If c1 IsNot Nothing And c2 IsNot Nothing Then
        tlp.Controls.SetChildIndex(c1, 1)
        tlp.Controls.SetChildIndex(c2, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Neolisk You are right if you added controls with row and columns index, in the sample that is used they were added without. So it did indeed work in my working application as I was adding UserControls with the Controls.Add(UCName) syntax. Your method is correct though for all situations